# IntelliJ problems with creating/editing Grails TagLib

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I've tried to create a TagLib using IntelliJ (right click on taglib -> New -> Grails TagLib)
I got the following error in Grails Console

> | Error Command not found create-tag-lib
>   Did you mean: create-taglib or create-unit-test or create-script?

However "Run Grails Command" create-taglib was successfully executed. But now when I try to open the TagLib file it's opened as a text file, not groovy.

I'm using Grails 3.1.4 and Intellij 2016.1

Comment: I've found what's the problem. There was a "Registered pattern" in "File Types" ( Settings -> Editor -> File Types) for the Text file type. Probably it was added while I was trying to create the TagLib as a regular file, and I haven't noticed it.